# Cómo resolver esperado org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, recibido org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, hadoop

Soy nuevo en hadoop y trato de ejecutar un programa de leer un archivo y que me agregue la cantidad de pacientes en un distrito en una BD, usando la estructura del mapreduce Estoy teniendo un error Error: java.io.IOException: Type notch in key del mapa: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text esperado, org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable recibido

```
public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Reducer.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String latitud;
        String longitud;
        String Line = value.toString();
        String tuple [] = Line.split("\\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < tuple.length; i++) {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            try {

                JSONObject objeto = (JSONObject) parser.parse(tuple[i]);
                latitud = objeto.get("latitud").toString();
                System.out.println(latitud);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "latitud" + latitud, "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                longitud = objeto.get("longitud").toString();
                System.out.println(longitud);
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "longitud" + longitud, "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                Integer id = Conexion.interseccion(latitud, longitud);

                if (id != 0) {
                    word.set(id.toString());
                    context.write(word, one);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error" + e.getMessage(), "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();


    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Reducer.Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        Conexion.actualizar(Integer.parseInt(key.toString()), sum);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Actualizar" + key.toString(), "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Cantidad" + sum, "error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.lang.Exception
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "CMAMO");
    job.setJarByClass(MapReduce.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

}
```

Mi clase conexión a la Bd:

```
public static int actualizar(int id, int cant) {
    if (id != 0) {
        Connection conex = getConexion();
        Statement stmf = null;
        try {
            stmf=conex.createStatement();
            String s_sqlF = "UPDATE distrito SET cantidad_de_pacientes=" + cant + "WHERE id=" + id;
            int n_res1= stmf.executeUpdate(s_sqlF);
            System.out.println("editado exitoso");
            return n_res1;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

public static int interseccion(String x, String y) {
    Connection conex = getConexion();
    Statement stmf = null;
  try {
      stmf=conex.createStatement();
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
    ResultSet s_sqlF = null;
  try {
      s_sqlF = stmf.executeQuery("select id from distrito "
              + "where geomCol1.STIntersects(geometry::Point("+x+","+y+",0)) = 1");
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
    int dis=0;
    try {
        while (s_sqlF.next()) {
            dis = s_sqlF.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
    return dis;
}
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

> Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, received org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1072) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.write(MapTask.java:715) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskInputOutputContextImpl.write(TaskInputOutputContextImpl.java:89) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.write(WrappedMapper.java:112) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.map(Mapper.java:125) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)